# Changing the background color of a popup menu in android

Tags: android, themes, popupmenu

I've been looking online for a solution to this but for some reason everything I have tried is not being reflected on the popup menu. Below is my attempt at trying to change the color of the popup menu however it has no affect and the popup menu's background is still black.

```
themes.xml
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2979FF</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#2962FF</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
</style>



<style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:background">#2979FF</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
   <item name="android:popupBackground">#2979FF</item>
</style>

Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.MyPopupMenu);
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(wrapper, view);
```

Comment: Thanks. Instead of "android:popupBackground" better type: <item name="android:background">@drawable/some_background_drawable</item>.